# How are Protected Media Path and similar systems implemented?

Tags: ios, windows, screen-capture, drm, dwm

Windows provides DRM functionality to applications that require it.

Some of them, however, have more protection than others.

As an example, take Edge (both Legacy and Chromium) or IE that use Protected Media Path. They get to display >720p Netflix content. Other browsers don't use PMP and are capped at 720p.

The difference in the protections is noticeable when you try to capture the screen: while you have no problems on Firefox/Chrome, in Edge/IE a fixed black image takes the place of the media you are playing, but you still see media control buttons (play/pause/etc) that are normally overlaid (alpha blended) on the media content.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA0ys.jpg) (not enough rep yet to post directly)

The question here is mainly conceptual, and in fact also could apply to systems that have identical behavior, like iOS that also replaces the picutre when you screenshot or capture the screen on Netflix.

How does it get to display *two* different images on two different outputs (Capture APIs with no DRM content and attached phisical monitor screen with DRM content)?

I'll make a guess and I'll start by excluding HW overlays. The reason is that play/pause buttons are still visible on the captured output. Since they are overlaid (alpha blended) on the media on the screen, and alpha blending on HW overlays is not possible in DirectX 9 or later nor it is using legacy DirectDraw, hardware overlays have to be discarded. And by the way, neither `d3d9.dll` or `ddraw.dll` are loaded by `mfpmp.exe` or `iexplore.exe` (version 11). Plus, I think hardware overlays are now considered a legacy feature, while Media Foundation (which Protected Media Path is a part of) is totally alive and maintained.

So my guess is that DWM, that is in charge for the screen composition, is actually doing two compositions. Either by forking the composition process at the point when it encounters a DRM area and feeds one output to the screen (with DRM protected content) and the other to the various screen capturing methods and APIs, or by entirely doing two different compositions in the first place.

Is my guess correct? And could you please provide evidence to support your answer?

My interest is understanding how composition software and DRM are implemented, primarily in Windows. But how many other ways could there be to do it in different OSes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/gpu-based-content-protection?redirectedfrom=MSDN), both the options are available.
The modern PlayReady DRM that Netflix uses for its playback in IE, Edge, and the UWP app uses the DWM method, which can be noticed by the video area showing only a black screen when DWM is forcibly killed. It seems that this is because the modern PlayReady is supported since Windows 8.1, which does not let users disable DWM easily.

I think both methods were used in Windows Vista-7, but I have no samples to test it. As HW overlays don't look that good with window previews, animations, and transparencies, they would have switched each method depending on the DWM status.

For iOS, it seems that a mechanism that is similar to the DWM method is done in the display server(SpringBoard?) level to present the protected content which is processed in the Secure Enclave Processor.